# Multiple iframes on a site all loading the same thing

Tags: html, css, iframe

so, here is the thing. I am currently building a website and it contains 11 iframes that load on click in an overlayed window. The problem is that each iframe loads the src link from the first iframe, not the one specified in its own src.

```js
function on() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#page {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="heading-title">
    <div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
        <div id="page">
            <iframe id="first" src="Site1.html" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="on()">
        <a>SITE ONE</a>
    </div>
</h2>
```

Does anyone know what could be causing the problem?

Comment: Please include code for your other 11 frames as well

Comment: _"The problem is that each iframe loads the src link from the first iframe"_ - I doubt that that is the _actual_ problem. Let me guess, this HTML snippet you have shown us, you repeated that multiple times - without changing the IDs used in there? IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document. If this _is_ what you did here, then the issue is that you are only ever _showing_ the first modal.

Comment: @Cbroe , I actually did change the ids.  The second one looks like this: 

<h2 class="heading-title">                      <div id="overlay" onclick="off()">                  <div id="page"><iframe id="second" src="Site2.html" height="100%"></iframe></div>                 </div>                 <div onclick="on()">                   <a>Box 1</a>                  </div>
</h2>

And for the rest, the ID changes into third, fourth etc.

Comment: `<div id="overlay"` - still the same ID, as in your first block, no? (The iframe IDs are not even used for _anything_ in what you have shown us so far, so _those_ are of really little relevance.)

Comment: Okay, I solved it. Thanks for the answers @Cbroe, they were really helpful albeit a bit snotty :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried listing iframes with an ascending numeric id? So that each iframe has a different id to avoid that all are called the same

Comment: I did, still the same thing

Comment: Can you publish some more code? something wrong has to be